# I need to show recent two wordpress posts in my codeigniter site at home page

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

Please provide the code for how to integrate. I kept blog inside at public_html folder and blog has one database and site has other database I have created.

I have tried these code at my site `index.php`

```
<?php require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');?>

<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 2, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
       <div class="events">
             <p><strong><?php the_date(); ?></strong></p>
           <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
      </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

but shows an error like

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_recent_posts() in 
/home/sharelok/public_html/application/views/index.php on line 124
```

Comment: You need to include `wp-load.php` file if you performing any wp operation outside wp.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('blog/wp-load.php');
$postslist = get_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'orderby'=> 'post_date' ) );
foreach( $postslist as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <div class="events">
       <p><strong><?php the_date(); ?></strong></p>
       <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare site_url() (previously declared in /home/sharelok/public_html/system/helpers/url_helper.php:42) in /home/sharelok/public_html/blog/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 1946

Comment: i'm getting above error but in local it shows like (error connecting database)

Comment: @leela, this is happening because, both `Ci` and `WP` has the function `site_url` and in the `require('blog/wp-load.php');` the `WP` is being included and thus `site_usl` is being declared in it's core. so, if you can rename `CI`is `site_url` then the problem will be solved, but I recommend you to follow [this article](http://philpalmieri.com/2009/06/codeigniter-and-wordpress-play-well-together/) and [this one](http://oscardias.com/development/php/codeigniter/integrating-wordpress-with-codeigniter/) too.